# Blackberry support for worklight pushnotification

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I read in the worklight v 6.1 in ibm information, that the worklight pushnotification is not supported in worklight in blackberry . Any idea how to implement push notification in blackberry using worklight.

Answer (score 0):

Since Worklight does not support Push Notifications in BlackBerry 6,7 and 10... You can't use any Worklight tools or APIs for that.

What you will need to do, is read the BlackBerry documentation regarding their Push Service for WebWorks-based apps and experiment with the implementation within your app: http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_1/push_service.html

Comment: I dont know about blackberry. Can give some more documentation to implement this is worklight

Comment: @BalajiSabdharM, please carefully read my answer - Worklight does not support Push Notifications in BlackBerry. This means there is no API from Worklight that you can use for Push Notifications in BlackBerry. If you want to add to your Worklight project push support in BlackBerry, read the BlackBerry documentation. Start from there. Read.